# Turn off Codeigniter 404 errors?

Tags: codeigniter

Due to historical reasons, we are using Codeigniter with only some of our projects, not site-wide. For instance,

- http://example.com/CI_project_1/
- http://example.com/CI_project_2/
- http://example.com/not_CI_1/
- http://example.com/not_CI_2/
- ...

We already have a nice custom 404 page via Apache settings, say:

- http://example.com/not_CI/custom_404.html

Now, with CI doing it's job, 404 errors that happen in /CI_project*/ are shown CI's error view, not custom_404.html. Unfortunately that's not what we want though; I know I can set a custom 404 view with `$route['404_override']`, but that has to be routed to a CI controller, not a regular URL. In the spirit of "DRY", I would also prefer not having to create a identical view in CI.

How do I "turn off" 404 error handling in CI, so that custom_404.html can do it's job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what I had in mind but here's what I did as a workaround:

```
/CI_project/error/error_404.php
```

Replace that with a symbolic link to /not_CI/custom_404.html.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your .htaccess file: `ErrorDocument 404 /custom_404.html`